# php allows javascript code to run

Tags: javascript, php, html

Good nigth guys, I have a problem..

```
<fieldset class="form-group inline-label">
     <textarea name="historia" class="form-control" maxlength="2000" minlength="700" placeholder="Minimo de 700 caracteres" requiredstyle="width:568px;height:180px;"></textarea>
<label for="formGroupExampleInput2">História:</label>
</fieldset>
```

I have more than this example but I'm using this one to explain. I have this textarea.
I save the value to the database like this : 
$historia = $_POST['historia'];

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO pendentes(blabla phistoria,blabla) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
if($stmt = $ligacao->prepare($sql))
{$stmt->bind_param("blabla", blabla, $historia);
$stmt->execute();                                 
$stmt->close();
```

And If I insert and for example: ?> alert("Something Something");
it will save on the database and run when the page is open
How can I fix it? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: @Ivonet Sorry, forgot to add, going to edit

Comment: No I did not forget to add, I add the rest of the text after the tag "<?php" and the site didin't showed

Comment: @CyRossignol I will read it better but yes it looks like it's that, thank you

Comment: @user7393973 it's just that is accepting javascript on the textarea and saving it on the database, and after when I do a select of that table it runs the javascript code

Comment: Use the htmlentities function when you print